# How to pass additional data to restful API Basic authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, coldfusion, restful-architecture, taffy

I am developing my first restful API for a project.

I understand and have gotten the basic authentication to work properly, using the format `Basic username:password` where username:password is Base64 encoded.

Currently, we pass a user's email address in the 'username' field and their password in the 'password' field.

The problem is that the email address is not unique in the application. It is unique per Organisation within the application.

So in order to log the user in successfully, we need to pass another value to the API which indicates what the organisation is (the idea would be to pass along a key that would be used to look up the organisation)

My issue is that the basic authentication process only allows you to pass two values (username,password), whereas I need to pass three. Is there a way to pass more data to the basic authentication process? Or do I have to use some other type of authentication to achieve this?

My idea was to modify the basic authentication so that it takes three values, for example: username:password:orgkey
I don't know if that is allowed or goes against the protocol for basic authentication though?

Although this question really is language independent, for the record I am using Coldfusion and the Taffy plugin.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What you're suggesting does go against the protocol for basic authentication.  However, you could pass a concatenated user name and figure it out on the other side.  For example, pass a username that is a combination of the organization and the user name, with a pipe | character in between.  Something like myUsername|myOrganization:myPassword.  Then on the back end, simply split the username into two variables and process them individually.

Comment: What if you first prompted for the organization's name/code, verify that it exists, then ask for credentials?

Comment: @DavidByers - this (your suggestion) is the route we are going to take for initial development and then convert to the token approach suggested below once we move from proof of concept to production. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic authentication is not a good protocol for securing web APIs as I tried to explain in my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31751220/18044) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27138900/18044).

It's okay to support it for things like test automation etc, but I would not use it in production. You will have a hard time keeping the password secret as neither JavaScript nor mobile clients can be trusted to keep secrets.

It's not clear to me why email addresses are not unique across organizations. Are you not sending the part after the at-sign ('@')?

You cannot introduce another field in the basic authentication credentials field. According to [RFC7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-2.1), the credentials field can only contain:

```
    credentials = auth-scheme [ 1*SP ( token68 / #auth-param ) ]
```

I would look into a security token based authentication scheme like using [JWT tokens](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token).

Comment: I'm not sure whether the author wants to use this webservice authentication in a hardcoded way. If that would be the case, tokens are of course the better solution. However, it looks like his webservice requires authentication by multiple parties within his organization. In this case, basic authentication looks like the proper solution.

Comment: Unique mail adresses: Maybe his organization uses some kind of a internal mail service (e.g. somebody@companyname.local).

Comment: To answer your questions about the email address, the system is a SAAS application that allows the same email to register and be used across different organisations on the platform. Therefore a user with the email user1@email.com could register at Org1 and Org2 using the same email address. This is a deliberate and necessary requirement of the platform - hence the question. When a user signs in on the web, we know the organisation by the subdomain. With an API, we don't, thus the question.

Comment: Thanks for the token suggestion - I was aware of this but didn't want to complicate and drag out things for the proof of concept version of the API, thus we David Byer's suggestion for now. For production however, we will definitely be using a more secure approach like you suggested.